# Jupyter can't find Kernels

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Jupyter Lab on Ubuntu and it doesn't find any kernels. In the "Select Kernel" modal, the only option is "No Kernel".

In the console I get the errors:

```
[W 2021-09-08 15:21:09.834 ServerApp] Kernel 'Python 3' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[W 2021-09-08 15:21:09.850 ServerApp] Kernel 'Python 2' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[W 2021-09-08 15:21:09.868 ServerApp] Kernel 'local-venv' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[W 2021-09-08 15:21:09.888 ServerApp] Kernel 'R' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
```

I have python2, python3 and R kernels installed and they are working in Hydrogen. I tried both installing them globally and running:

```
pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

As well as from a virtualenv with:

```
source your-venv/bin/activate
(your-venv)$ pip install jupyter
(your-venv)$ ipython kernel install --name "local-venv" --user
```

Am I missing something?

Edit:

```
$jupyter kernelspec list

[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Kernel 'Python 3' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Kernel 'Python 2' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Kernel 'local-venv' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
[ListKernelSpecs] WARNING | Kernel 'R' is referencing a kernel provisioner ('local-provisioner') that is not available.  Ensure the appropriate package has been installed and retry.
No kernels available
```

Comment: Not really a solution I understand, but upgrading python3.6 to python3.9 solved the issue for me